# How to calculate the access limit that my website can support

Tags: jmeter, limit, web-component-tester

I want to test my website, so I first want to calculate the limit it can support before taking it down.

I think that with the system hardware information I can arrive at the value of simultaneous accesses

Does anyone know a calculation method or an article?

I've already done some tests with access tools on the site, but I want to test the limit

Comment: Define 'access limit'.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can "calculate", this is something you can **measure**, you basically need to run a [Stress Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) against your site.

1. Find a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) which supports all [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) used by your website
2. Come up with a test script which will mimic real user accessing your web site network footprint
3. Start with 1 virtual user and [gradually increase the load](https://groups.google.com/g/lr-loadrunner/c/GODuruA5jws) until response time starts exceeding acceptable values or errors start occurring.

This would be the maximum number of users which your website can support on the given hardware and software configurations.